# How to create a List of Object in Back4App?

Tags: flutter, back4app

I'm using back4app in my application and I have a class like this called Meal:

[image]

and this is my code snippet :

```
class EatenMeals with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Meal> _eatenMeals = [];

  List<Meal> get eatenMeals {
    return [..._eatenMeals];
  }

  void addMeal(Meal meal) {
    var newMeal = Meal(
        id: meal.id,
        cal: meal.cal,
        catId: meal.catId,
        title: meal.title,
        duration: meal.duration,
        affordability: meal.affordability,
        imageUrl: meal.imageUrl,
        ingredients: meal.ingredients,
        isBreakfast: meal.isDinner,
        isDinner: meal.isDinner,
        isLunch: meal.isLunch,
        steps: meal.steps);

    _eatenMeals.add(newMeal);
  }
}
```

Now I want to create a class that contain list of Meals object.
and attach to users how do I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide your code snippet what you have achieved so far

Comment: Please edit your question with the code snippet instead of puttin it in the comments.

Comment: You are using Parse Server aren't you?

Comment: yes Parse server via back4app.com

Comment: I want to have a specific list for each user that retrieve their daily plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [Parse Server Custom Objects](https://pub.dev/packages/parse_server_sdk_flutter#objects). Here is an example for your case how to create a Custom Object for Meal.

```
class Meal extends ParseObject implements ParseCloneable {
  Meal() : super(_keyTableName);
  Meal.clone() : this();

  /// Looks strangely hacky but due to Flutter not using reflection, we have to
  /// mimic a clone
  @override
  clone(Map map) => Meal.clone()..fromJson(map);

  /// Colum names
  static const String _keyTableName = 'Meal';
  static const String keyCatId = 'catId';
  static const String keyTitle = 'title';
  static const String keyImgUrl = 'imgUrl';
  static const String keyIngredients = 'ingredients';
  static const String keySteps = 'steps';
  static const String keyCalorie = 'calorie';
  static const String keyDuration = 'duration';
  static const String keyAffordability = 'affordability';
  static const String keyIsBreakfast = 'isBreakfast';
  static const String keyIsLunch = 'isLunch';
  static const String keyIsDinner = 'isDinner';

  /// Getter & Setters
  List<String> get catId => get<List<String>>(keyCatId);
  set name(List<String> catId) => set<List<String>>(keyCatId, catId);
  
  String get title => get<String>(keyTitle);
  set title(String title) => set<String>(keyTitle, title);
  
  Strin> get imgUrl => get<String>(keyImgUrl);
  set imgUrl(String imgUrl) => set<String>(keyImgUrl, imgUrl);
  
  List<String> get ingredients => get<List<String>>(keyIngredients);
  set ingredients(List<String> ingredients) => set<List<String>>(keyIngredients, ingredients);
  
  List<String> get steps => get<List<String>>(keySteps);
  set steps(List<String> steps) => set<List<String>>(keySteps, steps);
  
  num get calorie => get<num>(keyCalorie);
  set calorie(num calorie) => set<num>(keyCalorie, calorie);
  
  num get duration => get<num>(keyDuration);
  set affordability(num duration) => set<num>(keyDuration, duration);
  
  String get affordability => get<String>(keyAffordability);
  set name(String affordability) => set<String>(keyAffordability, affordability);
  
  bool get isBreakfast => get<bool>(keyIsBreakfast);
  set isBreakfast(bool isBreakfast) => set<bool>(keyIsBreakfast, isBreakfast);
  
  bool get isLunch => get<bool>(keyIsLunch);
  set isLunch(bool isLunch) => set<bool>(keyIsLunch, isLunch);
  
  bool get isDinner => get<bool>(keyIsDinner);
  set isDinner(bool isDinner) => set<bool>(keyIsDinner, isDinner);
}
```

Then you have to register this subclass.

```
Parse().initialize(
   ...,
   registeredSubClassMap: <String, ParseObjectConstructor>{
     'Meal': () => Meal(),
   },
);
```